# OpenID Connect - adding custom attributes (claims) to id token

Tags: oauth2, open-id-connect

I'm having trouble getting a custom claim attribute to come through in the `id_token`. I've got the scope set to `openid` and I've added the custom attribute to the Connected App (`tenantId`). I also tried implementing a connected app plugin and overiding the `customAttributes` method.

I checked *Configure Id Token* in the connected app config page and made sure custom claims was ticked (along with standard claims).

All of the above, and I keep getting back an `id_token` without the additional claim information. Have I missed anything? I know that i can make a call to the `UserInfo` endpoint, but i'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get custom attributes in the `id_token` upon enabling *Include Custom Attributes* as explained in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_security_auth_id_tokens.htm)

Following is what I get when I try the flow using https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/

```
{
 "at_hash": "qzgoS_bMJZeqMG891R61HQ",
 "aud": "3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp6DzCgTCe.0uVYD_Gk1LZ3Dm8V3DepaqufgLARbdL0snwm8_LrT4mdbN_fBxKYoy0UGOHpj",
 **"custom_attributes": {"ProfileCreatedById": "00590000001VSXz"},**
 "exp": 1553370624,
 "iat": 1553370504,
 "iss": "https://login.salesforce.com",
 "sub": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000iulkEAA/00590000001VSXzAAO"
}
```