# Adding custom claims to access token in oAuth JWT Bearer flow

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, jwt

My requirement is to retrieve additional attributes via JWT Flow. For that 
I developed a connected app plugin class and added it to the connected app. Although i am able to get the access token, it doesn't contain additional attributes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenID Connect - adding custom attributes (claims) to id token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254623/salesforce-oauth2-custom-attributes-claims)

Comment: To summarize the referenced answer: it's possible in an OpenID Connect flow with id tokens - this flow/token combo is intended for your use case. Not possible with access tokens in any flow.

Comment: @identigral As far as i understand your ans is 

First is we can send additional attributes with id tokens in both case SAML and JWT.
However in each case where  in response where we used to get access token, could not make it. Right!!